WPF Databinding to a User Control
I am trying to create a simply User Control to set the Value, SelectionStart & SelectionEnd properties in a slider and are having some success but I can only set the properties at compile time. The SetValue in the dependency property is not firing when setting the property and so the databinding link is somehow incorrect.
I have placed the code into a small project to simplify it.
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyExample"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyExample.User_Controls"
    
    x:Name="MainWin"
    
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Slider Test"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Height="450"
    Width="200">

    <Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Position, ElementName=userTest}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <uc:UserTest x:Name="userTest" Position="{Binding Path=Pos}" Set_Title="THUMB" Set_SelStart="{Binding Path=Start}" Set_SelEnd="{Binding Path=End}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,20" />

    <Label Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider1, StringFormat=\{0:D0\}}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Slider x:Name="Slider1" Value="50" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" SelectionStart="10" SelectionEnd="90" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Maximum="100" SmallChange="1" Margin="0,45,0,24" />

    <Button x:Name="btn_Press" Content="Press" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,10,10,10" Click="btn_Press_Click" />
</Grid>

The Main code-behind.
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyname = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }


    private double _start { get; set; }

    public double Start
    {
        get { return _start; }
        set 
        {
            _start = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Start");
        }
    }

    private double _end { get; set; }

    public double End
    {
        get { return _end; }
        set
        {
            _end = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("End");
        }
    }

    private double _pos { get; set; }

    public double Pos
    {
        get { return _pos; }
        set
        {
            _pos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Pos");
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        Start = 10;
        End = 90;
        Pos = 50;
    }

    private void btn_Press_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Start = 30;
        End = 60;
        Pos = 70;
    }
}

The user control "UserTest" with the name window name as "SliderRoot".
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="title" Content="{Binding Set_Title, ElementName=SliderRoot}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />

    <Slider x:Name="Digit_Slider" 
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Value="{Binding Position, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            SelectionStart="{Binding Set_SelStart, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            SelectionEnd="{Binding Set_SelEnd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="0,5,0,5" 
            Maximum="100" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
            IsDirectionReversed="True" 
            Cursor="Hand"
            ValueChanged="Digit_Slider_ValueChanged" />
</Grid>

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Title_Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Set_Title", typeof(string), typeof(UserTest), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public static DependencyProperty SelStart_Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Set_SelStart", typeof(double), typeof(UserTest), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnSelStart_Changed));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelEnd_Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Set_SelEnd", typeof(double), typeof(UserTest), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnSelEnd_Changed));

    public static DependencyProperty Pos_Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(double), typeof(UserTest), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnPosition_Changed));

    private static void OnSelStart_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var User = d as UserTest;
        User.Digit_Slider.SelectionStart = (double)e.NewValue;
    }

    private static void OnSelEnd_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var User = d as UserTest;
        User.Digit_Slider.SelectionEnd = (double)e.NewValue;
    }

    private static void OnPosition_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var User = d as UserTest;
        User.Digit_Slider.Value = (double)e.NewValue;
    }

    // Set TITLE (string) property of Slider
    public string Set_Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Title_Property); }
        set { SetValue(Title_Property, value); }
    }

    // Set SELECTION START (double) property of Slider
    // MODE = 1 Way (Write)
    public double Set_SelStart
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(SelStart_Property); }
        set { SetValue(SelStart_Property, value); }
    }

    // Get VALUE (double) property of Slider
    // MODE = 2 Way (Read / Write)
    public double Position
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(Pos_Property); }
        set { 
            SetValue(Pos_Property, value); 
        }
    }

    // Set SELECTION END (double) property of Slider
    public double Set_SelEnd
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(SelEnd_Property); }
        set { SetValue(SelEnd_Property, value); }
    }

    #endregion DEPENDENCY_PROPERTIES

    public UserTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

I can set the values manually in XAML and they show ok but not if I set the values when I press a button.
I am nearly there but I am missing something, probably simple.

This might help wpf-slider-with-an-event-that-triggers-after-a-user-drags

I guess your change notification isn't working because main window doesn't implement inotifypropertychanged. I also recommend view models as separate classes. Auto generate your boiler plate code by using mvvm community toolkit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/

I have manually included the OnPropertyChanged() event and put a breakpoint in there and it fires ok and changed the value but the value never appears on the slider object, not event the standard slider.

Your window needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. That doesn't mean just have an event satisfies the interface.

I can set the value property and change the slider track position in my constructor but not while it is running.

SO I could create a class and use the interface and do it that way?

There is also a mandatory naming convention for dependency properties. The identifier field of a property named X must be named XProperty. So if you have a property named Title (not Set_Title which is a nonsensical name anyway), the identifier field must be named TitleProperty. You would also use nameof(Title) as the first argument to the Register method.

Your "button click" sets a range; then tries to set a position "outside" of that range.

I would suspect in binding issue , although I agree that you should use MVVM as commented by others, you can try fixing the binding -
replace the new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
with new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
or in the binding set to two way , random example:
Text="{Binding UserInput, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 


That's what I think but the XAML Binding Failures is zero.

I have tried the changes above but no joy.
